# Storing arrangement of same word efficiently

Tags: data-structures, tree, trie, data-storage, data-retrieval

I had a question related to Dictionary storage.

I was reading about Trie Data-structures and so far I have read that it works pretty well as  prefix tree. But, I came to Trie - DS in efforts to see if it can reduce the storage of arrangement of letters formed through same word efficiently.

For ex : words "ANT", "TAN" and NAT have same letters but according to Trie it goes on to create two separate paths for these words. I can understand that Trie is meant for prefix storage and reduce redundancy. But can anyone help me in reducing the redundancy here.
One way I was thinking was to change the behavior of Trie as to each node has a status of 'word complete'; In addition if I put 'word start' status too I can make this work as below :

```
A
N - A - T
T - A - N
```

Now, every time I can check if the word is starting form here and go till the end.

Does this makes sense ? and if this is feasible ?
Or is their any better method to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 tries and also store the reverse trie. Then you can use a wildcard expansion everywhere in the search for example you can split the search word into 2 half and search for one half by the prefix and the other half by its suffix:http://phpir.com/tries-and-wildcards/. When you concatenate the 2 you can efficient search with a wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a status field to each node you will increase the memory cost of your tree (assuming 8-bit chars) by a possibly not insignificant portion.

I understand that you want to reduce the number of letters in the DS, but you have to consider what happens if some contents are subsets of other contents, e.g. how ANTAN would be represented. Think about the minimal number of chars (128) as nodes of a fully connected graph. Obviously all words are stored in this graph, however it is not suitable to store any specific words. There is no way of telling where words end. The information stored in a trie is not just letters, but complete and properly terminated words.

If you add a marker as you suggest, how will you be able to encode this: SUPERCHARGED, SUPER, PERCH. You would set word_starts at S and P and word_ends at R and H. How would you know that SUPERCH and PER are not contained? You could instead use a non-zero label and assign number-pairs to the beginning and end of words: S:1 P:2 R:1 H:2. To make sure that start and end can occur at the same letter, you would have to use specific bits as labels.

You could then use NATANT as minimal flat representation and N:001 A:000 T:011 A:100 N:010 T: 100. This requires #words bit for the marker in the worst case: A, AA, AAA.... If you would store that in a tree however, you would have to look for the other marker, which is not an operation supported by trees. So I see no good way of using a marker.

From an information theoretical point I think the critical issue here is to properly encode the length, ordering and contents of a word in a unique way for each possible combination of these.

I originally meant to just comment, but it got a bit lengthy. I am not sure if this answers your question, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you hoping that any search for "ant" also brings up "tan" and "nat"?

If so, then use a TrieMap, always sort keys before reads/writes and map to a container of all words in that "anagram class."

If you're just looking for ideas to reduce the space overhead of using a Trie, then look no further. I've found [burst trie](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~jz/fulltext/acmtois02.pdf)'s to be very space efficient. I wrote my own [burst trie in Scala](https://github.com/nbauernfeind/scala-burst-trie) that also re-uses some ideas that I found in [GWT's trie implementation](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PrefixTree.java?r=3512).